# Change only last number of last page in page range in Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

My university's referencing style requires that for a page range, the digits for the last page should only be those digits that have not changed from the first page, e.g. 653-6, 643-53, 540-750.

I am modifying a copy of `unsrtnat`.

I am very new to TeX and I am struggling to work out how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: biblatex has commands and options for this (see `\mkcomprange` in the documentation). Perhaps you should switch to the package instead of trying to adjust a `.bst`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way is to do it manually in the .bib file by changing the pages you're inserting:

```
pages = "253--268"    ->    pages = "253--68"
```

Comment: This would mean the loss of information from my bibliographic data, which doesn't sit right with me.